# Turning off main water line

Tags: water

How long is it safe to have a main water line turned off to your house?  We are gone from  the home for 6 months. Will we have problems with leaks when we turn this water back on?

Comment: Do you have some specific problem with your plumbing that you believe might start leaking due to lack of water supply?

Comment: Pipes usually don't care.  frozen pipes might leak.  Might loosen sediment in the pipes when water is turned on again.

Comment: If you have hot-water (hydronic) heating system, and it's left on during vacation (e.g., to prevent damage from freezing pipes or water closets), there is need to make up water lost from the system from expansion overflow or leakage. Without water in the system, it's likely to be permanently damaged.

Comment: A hydronic heating system in good repair should neither leak nor expand to the point of overflow. That this is both possible and normal is demonstrated by those which use anti-freeze and are not connected directly to plumbing, and those that are connected directly to plumbing with a valve kept closed except in the event of system servicing - both of which are normal cases. Leaky systems that need constant refilling are also out there, of course, but they should be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Many seasonal dwellings have water turned off for 3-9 months a year, or 17 if not used for a particular year.

It's impossible to predict whether you will have leaks when turned back on, but at least you'll be there, which is better than 5.9 months of a leak that starts right after you leave with the water supply on.

Quality plumbing should have few issues - your major concern with the water being off that long is sealing your traps so they don't evaporate dry and permit sewer gas into the house - and freezing, if that's a potential in your area - heating systems can fail...in which case fully draining all the plumbing and putting non-toxic anti-freeze in the traps is wise (and, again, common for seasonal dwellings.)

However, it's fairly common for main shutoffs that are basically never used to fail when finally used, especially if they are older gate valves. Far better to operate it every few months than to let it sit for years. Ball-type 1/4 turn shutoff valves do better at rare use, but it's still good to check that they actually can be moved and do work once or twice a year.

*Uncommonly* old valves might have packing "dry out" and weep a bit - they will either stop when it gets wet, or you'll repack them with modern packing that does not shrink or swell. Or replace them, but repacking is likely all they would need if that were the case.

*Alternatively, and depending on location, move the precious items into safe storage and put the house in the care of a rental agency/service so **it gets used and you get some income**, rather than having it sit idle for 6 months*

Comment: I would consider turning the hot water off, and have a neighbor check the house regularly or hire a service to do that.  They can run water in the sinks and flush the you know what, keeping the aroma where it belongs not in the home. I also restrict my main water feed to a small flow just in case there is a leak the sump pump can get rid of most of it.If you use sprinklers do not do that.

Comment: We're all adults here, @Gil, you can say "commode" or even "toilet". Just skip the sophomoric euphemisms.